# Why is my landing page (built in jquery mobile) targeting to content (below header)?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Please see www.lancoministorage.com as an example.  When I load this site up on my iPhone, the content displays at the top (starting with the call button), and the header is not seen unless someone would manually pull the screen down.  Is there a way I can get this to load with the header image displaying at the top?

This is how I did my main layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lanco Mini Storage</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Lanco Mini Storage">
</div>
<!--header-->
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="a" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="tel:7172916022">Call Us at (717) 291-6022</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:info@lancoministorage.com">Send Us an Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="turn">Map to Our Location</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hours" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="turn">Hours of Operation</a></li>
        </ul>

</div><!--content-->
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" class="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/view-full-site.asp" rel="external" data-icon="home">View Full Website</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--navbar-->
</div><!--footer-->
</div><!--page-->
```

...page content continued (not shown)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: yeah i think you might need to load up jquery mobile to your site

Comment: I did in my header.  Sorry, I did not paste everything.  Is this what you are referring to? (see amended code above)

Comment: Try using jquery 1.9 and JQM 1.3.2 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I updated the jquery version.  Seems to still be doing the same thing.

Comment: Your website works normally on iPhone 5 and iPad 2.